# Upgrading PHP FreeType Version from 2.2.1 to 2.4.4 in Apache with WHM

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, whm, freetype

I've created a PHP app using GD on my local server (MAMP) and everything works perfectly, now I've put it up online it's displaying differently...

The only difference as far as i can see by comparing `phpinfo()` on the local and live servers is the FreeFont version (2.2.1 and 2.4.4). I have access to WHM on a dedicated server, but can't see how i update this version so everything works again!

My Apache and WHM skills are limited, but there must be a semi simple way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is displaying differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade the development libraries for FreeType so next time you compile PHP through WHM EasyApache it uses the newer lib files from FreeType when building the FreeType extension.

On CentOS, do `yum install freetype-devel` or `yum update freetype-devel` since you probably already have it installed.  Then rebuild PHP through EasyApache and you should have the newer version.

Comment: Where do i run `yum update freetype-devel` in WHM? Really new to playing about with WHM sorry!

Comment: You have to run that from the server console or SSH in and run the command from shell.  You may also be able to get it to update from `Main >> Software >> Update Server Software` in WHM but if you run it from the shell you can see better what version it updates to.  If the CentOS version you are on is older and you already are at the latest version, you will have to uninstall the package and manually compile and install FreeType to get a newer version.

Comment: ok... that gives me: `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * extras: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * updates: mirror01.th.ifl.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Package freetype-devel-2.2.1-31.el5_8.1.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do` but on the freetype website and on MAMP it says a higher version is available...

Comment: You must have an older version of CentOS where that version of FreeType is the latest stable version tested with the OS.  You can see your version by running `cat /etc/centos-release`.  So you can either update to a newer OS version (probably not recommended) or you can uninstall the yum FreeType package and manually compile it from the latest source on freetype.org.  Installation is straightforward, the docs/README.UNIX file explains how to compile and install it.